# Why is this scipy.root code not converging?

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations, scipy-optimize

I'm running a test problem to set up larger problems. Solving the simple unsteady heat equation via finite differences:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy import optimize
import pandas as pd
from numba import njit

t_max = 25
x_max = 1
N_points_1 = 61
N_points_2 = 11
dt = t_max/(N_points_1-1) 
dx = x_max/(N_points_2-1)
N_variables = N_points_1 * N_points_2
alpha = 0.01 
T_x_0 = 60 
T_x_L = 25
T_t_0 = 25

@njit
def EDP (v):
    T_N =  np.ones((N_points_1, N_points_2))
    
    #Variables
    k=0
    for i in range(N_points_1):
        for j in range(N_points_2): 
            T_N[i,j]=v[k]
            k=k+1
            
    #Model
    sys = []
    ##Boundary Condition x = 0
    for i in range(N_points_1):
        BC1 = T_N[i,0] - T_x_0
        sys.append(BC1)

    ##Boundary Condition x = L
    for i in range(N_points_1):
        BC2 = T_N[i,-1] - T_x_L
        sys.append(BC2)

    ##Initial Condition
    for j in range(1,N_points_2-1):
        IC1 = T_N[0,j] - T_t_0
        sys.append(IC1)

    ## Energy Balance 
    for i in range(N_points_1-1):
        for j in range (1,N_points_2 -1):
            EB = alpha*(T_N[i,j+1]-2*T_N[i,j]+T_N[i,j-1])/dx**2 - (T_N[i+1,j]-T_N[i,j])/dt  
            sys.append(EB)
    
    sys=np.array(sys)

    
    return sys

initial_guess = np.linspace(25,60,N_variables)        
function_compile = EDP(initial_guess)
```

I tested the following scipy.root algorithms:

```
Solution_T = fsolve(EDP,initial_guess)
Solution_T = optimize.anderson(EDP,initial_guess, verbose = True,maxiter = 1000)  
Solution_T = optimize.newton_krylov(EDP,initial_guess,verbose=True,maxiter = 1000)
Solution_T = optimize.broyden1(EDP,initial_guess,verbose=True,maxiter = 1000)
Solution_T = optimize.broyden2(EDP,initial_guess,verbose=True,maxiter = 1000)
```

And ONLY fsolve converges(instantly, in fact) but since i am just running a test for a larger run(which will contain about 50000 variables), fsolve won't be able to handle that and the scipy docs recommends the algorithms mentioned above, but none of them converge.

They either diverge with the objective function overflowing or remain stuck in the same value, not converging. As for why i am not using linear solvers, its because i intend to input more complex non-linear equations later.

Thanks

Comment: Often this is due to bad initial guesses

Comment: Doesn't look like it https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42582/scipy-root-not-converging-even-when-provided-with-initial-guesses-very-close-to

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to solve numerically equations like this, it is usually better to express it as `min(||F(x)||)` instead of trying to find `F(x)=0` these two formulations are equivalent when a solution exist, but if it is not possible to get an exact solution this tell you what is the closest you can get from a solution.

[least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) works for your example, and it has a few parameters that you can tune to somewhat improve the method performance

```py
sol = optimize.least_squares(EDP, initial_guess)
print(sum(EDP(sol.x)**2))
```

```
1.383176178225409e-26
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything in the equation that makes it not well fit to be solved by the root finders? I even made another question in scicomp https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42582/scipy-root-not-converging-even-when-provided-with-initial-guesses-very-close-to . Where i put very good initial conditions and still they don't converge.

Comment: I don't know the details of the underlying methods of the multi dimensional solver functions, the only root finding algorithms that I used in the past are the 1D. For multidimensional problems I always use minimization functions. Maybe the estimates for the jacobians are not working. In your case that you use a regular grid you can write your function without numba.